# How do I add a persistent configuration option to 'ag'?

Tags: ag

I have recently begun to use the 'ag' command instead of 'ack'.

Ag is much faster, but does not seem to have a file (such as .ackrc) where one could add configuration options.

For example, I always want a pager to be used, and I don't want to have to always type in:

```
ag --pager "less -R"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about putting the following in your command line configuration file (such as .bashrc or .zshrc)?

```
alias ag="ag $* --pager 'less -R'"
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can always add `--nopager` when invoking the command to override. This is useful for flags that don't play nicely with `--pager 'less -R'`, such as `--stats`

Comment: Personally I like to use a different thing on the right hand side - alias ag="/bin/ag $* --pager 'less -R'" (where /bin/ag should be replaced with your location of the ag binary)

Answer (score -2):

Hope this is not way too late.

Run `man ag` on linux box. Right at the end if the following text:

> By default, ag will ignore files matched by patterns in .gitignore,
>   .hgignore, or .agignore. These files can be anywhere in the
>   directories being searched. Ag also ignores files matched by the
>   svn:ignore property in sub‐
>          version repositories. Finally, ag looks in **$HOME/.agignore** for ignore patterns. Binary files are ignored by default as well.

Note the part I emphasised. So just add `.agignore` file and ignore patterns in there

  -

---

Comment: It looks like your answer is about ignoring files.  I actually wanted to be able to adjust paging.